# How I can capture popup close event in Android?

Tags: android

How I can capture popup close event in Android? I want to perform some action when popup window is closed by user.

Comment: see `DialogInterface.OnCancelListener`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Override `OnCancelListener`..

```
dialog.setOnCancelListener(new OnCancelListener() {         
@Override
public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
    //do somethiing
}
});
```

if you are using `PopupWindow` then override `PopupWindow.OnDismissListener`

Comment: The above comment is the real answer.